# best way to update/add nest redux state

Tags: react-native, react-redux, immutable.js, ramda.js

I am using react native with redux, my UI can increase value of an attr with below format

```
{
  'page1': {
    'attrs': [
      {
        'attr1': {
          'value': 10
        }
      },
      {
        'attr2': {
          'value': 20
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

three cases when add attr:

1. if attr, e.g. 'attr2' already exist, increase its value
2. if the attr, e.g. 'attr3' is not existed, add a new attr
3. if the page, e.g. 'page2' is not exist, add a new page and then a new attr

It would be a lot of logic for null checking and looping the list. Any shorthand or best way for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can improve your data structure a bit to make updating easier. 
In your case there is no need for "attrs" to be an array. You can do something like this:

```
{
    "page1": {
      "attrs": {
        "attr1": 10,
        "attr2": 20,
        "attr3": 30
      }
    }
}
```

So testing if an attribute exists should be as easy as this

```
if(page1.attrs[atrrName]) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be a simple way to deal with this using only Ramda.  Ramda's lenses are somewhat limited, borrowed from languages where data structures are more strict, and therefore less facile in working with partial structures.  You might want to look at the **[partial-lenses](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses)** library, which is designed around these sorts of problems.

---

### Update

On second thought, there is something to be said for using Ramda's lenses, even if the lens construction is pretty horrible.  I'm sure there's a better way to write this lens creator, but below is a possible solution.

Once you create the lens, you can use it with Ramda's [`view`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#view), [`set`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#set), or (with a function like [`inc`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#inc)), [`over`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#over).  This makes for a consistent way of focusing on a particular attribute of a given page.

As I said, this lens constructor is pretty nasty, dealing with all the possible ways things could go wrong.  But the code using it is quite reasonable.

```js
const { lens, find, has, findIndex, assocPath, update, 
        append, assoc, view, set, over, inc} = R

const pageAttrValueLens = (pageName, attrName) => lens(
  (pages) => (find(
    has(attrName), 
    (pages[pageName] || {attrs: []}).attrs
  ) || {[attrName]: {value: 0}})[attrName].value,
  (val, pages) => {
    const page = pages[pageName] || {attrs: []}
    const attrIdx = findIndex(has(attrName), page.attrs)
    const idx = attrIdx === -1 ? page.attrs.length : attrIdx
    const attr = page.attrs[idx] || {[attrName]: {value: 0}}
    const newAttr = assocPath([attrName, 'value'], val, attr)
    const attrs = idx < page.attrs.length 
                ? update(idx, newAttr, page.attrs)
                : append(newAttr, page.attrs)
    const newPage = assoc('attrs', attrs, page)
    return assoc(pageName, newPage, pages)
  }
)

const pages = {
  'page1': {
    'attrs': [
      {'attr1': {'value': 10}},
      {'attr2': {'value': 20}}
    ]
  }
}

console.log(view(pageAttrValueLens('page1', 'attr2'), pages)) //=> 20
console.log(view(pageAttrValueLens('page1', 'attr3'), pages)) //=> 0
console.log(view(pageAttrValueLens('page2', 'attr1'), pages)) //=> 0

console.log(set(pageAttrValueLens('page1', 'attr2'), 42, pages))
  //=> {"page1":{"attrs":[{"attr1":{"value":10}},{"attr2":{"value":42}}]}}
console.log(set(pageAttrValueLens('page1', 'attr3'), 42, pages))
  //=> {"page1":{"attrs":[{"attr1":{"value":10}},{"attr2":{"value":20}},{"attr3":{"value":42}}]}}
console.log(set(pageAttrValueLens('page2', 'attr1'), 42, pages))
  //=> {"page1":{"attrs":[{"attr1":{"value":10}},{"attr2":{"value":20}}]},"page2":{"attrs":[{"attr1":{"value":42}}]}}


console.log(over(pageAttrValueLens('page1', 'attr2'), inc, pages))
  //=> {"page1":{"attrs":[{"attr1":{"value":10}},{"attr2":{"value":21}}]}}
console.log(over(pageAttrValueLens('page1', 'attr3'), inc, pages))
  //=> {"page1":{"attrs":[{"attr1":{"value":10}},{"attr2":{"value":20}},{"attr3":{"value":1}}]}}
console.log(over(pageAttrValueLens('page2', 'attr1'), inc, pages))
  //=> {"page1":{"attrs":[{"attr1":{"value":10}},{"attr2":{"value":20}}]},"page2":{"attrs":[{"attr1":{"value":1}}]}}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```